# Opening C program in Mac Terminal

Tags: c, terminal, command

I am having trouble opening a C program in terminal.
I do these following commands on terminal:

```
cd desktop
gcc -o avg avg.c -Wall -Werror
./avg numbers.txt
./a.out
```

`File name is missing`            (this is the output)

I am not sure why it's saying file name is missing.
Instead, I am supposed to receive an average number. 
My C program is avg.c and my input program is numbers.txt. 
I have both files in my desktop. 
What command am I doing wrong?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  if(argc == 1){
    printf("File name missing\n");
    return 1;
  }
```

Comment: Is it `./avg numbers.txt` or `./a.out` that produces the error message?  What is `a.out`?  Is it related to the code you show?

Comment: It would be helpful if you copy paste the terminal session fully (commands and output) instead of showing us commands separately, and output separately. Also make sure the folder has nothing else to begin with, just the avg.c (especially no file called a.out)